# Access existing MongoDB collection from meteor app

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collectionfs

In my MongoDB, I have a collection that I created and populated from the server side, called "fs.files" (It's a gridFS collection).

In my meteor app, is there a way to declare a global variable that simply can fetch me information from this database?

I tried

```
PDFs = new Mongo.Collection("fs.files");

PDFs = new FS.Collection("fs.files", {
    stores: [new FS.Store.FileSystem("fsfiles", {path: "./reports"})]
});
```

Both of them would return an empty array when I do PDFs.find().fetch()

The problem is, I do not want to create a new collection. I simply want to have access to an existing one since I do not create this database from client side.

Comment: are you sure your gridFS collection is kn the same database? the meteor default db is 'meteor', gridFS maya be storing data in its own db. check using the mongo client with `mongo localhost:3001/meteor` and see if you other collection is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach should work. You are likely forgetting to *publish* this collection on the server and *subscribe* to it on the client.

server:

```
Meteor.publish('myPDFs',function(){
  return PDFs.find();
});
```

client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('myPDFs');
```